# What is the << operator?

Tags: groovy

Just trying to understand a line of code which copies a file:

```
new File("c:\\test") << new File("c:\\test\\newtest").bytes
```

What is the `<<` known as ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `left shift operator`

That line of code is calling `File.leftShift( byte[] bytes )` (documentation [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#leftShift%28byte%5B%5D%29)), so is writing the bytes from `newtest` into `test`

Comment: Is the operator being overridden in this case ?

Comment: Yes, Groovy loves operator overloading.  [This article is from 2005](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg10255/index.html), but is still quite good and relevant.

Comment: Yes, it's overriden by the Groovy JDK extenstions to the File class http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#leftShift(byte[])